# Do we need [s] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is only one question with  [s](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/s) tag. There isn't information about this tag and [question where was used](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264971/qgis-2-18-gives-invalid-data-source) has no information about an "*s*" tool, action, data type, etc.

This tag can be confused with S software or even 6S radiative model.

I propose to delete it.

Comment: looks like a typo - thanks for identifying the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed - it appears to have been created by mistake, or possibly in the attempt to add a [shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapefile) tag.  There doesn't appear to be any other reason there is a [s](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/s) tag in that Q&A.

Comment: changed to shapefile tag

Comment: merged s to shapefile - marking as completed